# Gravar num Bloco de Notas C#

Tags: c#

Será que alguém me poderá ajudar no seguinte.
Pretendo colocar um `button` no meu programa, que ao clicar, grave o conteúdo de uma `Textbox` num Documento de Bloco de Notas na pasta que quisermos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
using System.IO; // Biblioteca Input/Output, importante para salvar e ler arquivos!

SaveFileDialog salvar = new SaveFileDialog(); // Cria instancia tipo SaveFileDialog
salvar.Filter = "Arquivos de Texto (*.txt)|*.txt"; // Mostra apenas arquivos de texto[opcional]
salvar.DefaultExt = "txt"; // Define a extensão padrão para arquivo de texto
DialogResult salvou = salvar.ShowDialog(); // Mostra o SaveFileDialog
if (salvou == DialogResult.Ok) // Só grava caso o usuário tenha clicado em OK          
{
    StreamWriter sw = null;
    try
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(salvar.FileName); // Cria Instancia tipo StreamWriter, para gravar o arquivo
        sw.WriteLine(textbox1.Text); // Grava o conteúdo do textbox1 no arquivo
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("IOException:\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message); // Mostra mensagem caso ocorra uma IOException
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception : \r\n\r\n" + ex.Message); //M ostra mensagem caso ocorra uma exceção que não seja do tipo IOException
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sw != null)
            sw.Close(); // Fecha a instancia StreamWriter, com ou sem exceção.
    }
}
else
{
    // Pode por um código aqui caso o usuário clique em cancel.
}
```

Para gravar o conteúdo de um ListBox, tente assim:

```
using System.IO; // Biblioteca Input/Output, importante para salvar e ler arquivos!

    SaveFileDialog salvar = new SaveFileDialog(); // Cria instancia tipo SaveFileDialog
    salvar.Filter = "Arquivos de Texto (*.txt)|*.txt"; // Mostra apenas arquivos de texto[opcional]
    salvar.DefaultExt = "txt"; // Define a extensão padrão para arquivo de texto
    DialogResult salvou = salvar.ShowDialog(); // Mostra o SaveFileDialog
    if (salvou == DialogResult.Ok) // Só grava caso o usuário tenha clicado em OK          
    {
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        try
        {
          sw = new StreamWriter(salvar.FileName); // Cria Instancia tipo StreamWriter, para gravar o arquivo
          for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) 
          { 
          sw.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[i]); //Vare o listbox e grava os itens, caso tenha algum.
          }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IOException:\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message); // Mostra mensagem caso ocorra uma IOException
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception : \r\n\r\n" + ex.Message); //M ostra mensagem caso ocorra uma exceção que não seja do tipo IOException
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sw != null)
                sw.Close(); // Fecha a instancia StreamWriter, com ou sem exceção.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Pode por um código aqui caso o usuário clique em cancel.
    }
```

OBS:

É importante fechar o `StreamWriter` para que possa visualizar o arquivo com outro aplicativo.

OBS2: Lebre-se de adicionar os itens no ListBox ;D

Answer (score 5):

Apenas complementando [a resposta do @JoãoPauloPulga](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57829/2999), como [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) deriva de [`TextWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.textwriter(v=vs.110).aspx), e `TextWriter` implementa [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), o seguinte código realiza o `Close` e o descarte correto do objeto `StreamWriter` após a gravação do arquivo:

```
if (salvou == DialogResult.Ok) { // Só grava caso o usuário tenha clicado em OK          
   using (var sw = new StreamWriter(salvar.FileName)) { // Cria Instancia tipo StreamWriter, para gravar o arquivo
        sw.WriteLine(textbox1.Text); // Grava o conteúdo do textbox1 no arquivo
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*== Só para complementar também as respostas já dadas ==*

É possível gravar um arquivo com [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (salvou == DialogResult.Ok)
{
    File.WriteAllText(
        salvar.FileName,
        textbox1.Text);
}
```

Assim não será preciso trabalhar com `StreamWriter`, com `using` nem `try/catch`, e nem ter de se preocupar com mais nada.